# why to put 32 behind thr regsvr32 while registering component object model?

Tags: com, regsvr32, dllregistration

I am excited to know that what is the specific purpose to put 32 behind regsvr. why not  regsvr64 ? In explain what is the significance of this 32 here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the same historical name, but you actually have two versions of `regsvr32.exe` on your 64-bit system:

`C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32.exe` - can register both 32 and 64 bit COM DLLs
`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe` - can only register 32 bit COM DLLs

Comment: so there is no significance of this 32 infact?

Comment: No, it's just the name. In fact `C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32.exe` is a 64-bit executable in a 64-bit OS.

Comment: @Nonseratio     Thnks for this information. i have one more question(very important) if you are able to help me on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361085/created-preview-handler-for-outlook-giving-extra-message  i had asked it about 1 week before but no replies yet .

Comment: Because may be it is related to registration process

Comment: I've looked at your other question and edited the list of tags, what should give it more exposure. But you should reformat your code to make it readable, otherwise it's unlikely you'll see some comments. I myself don't have an answer out of head.

Answer (score 3):

COM already existed back in the days of 16-bit Windows.  The "32" got appended to distinguish the 32-bit version of regsvr.exe, which is only capable of registering 32-bit COM servers.

They didn't do it the same way for the 64-bit version, that was solved another way by keeping the 32-bit and 64-bit components strictly separate.  Both in the registry and the file system.  The 32-bit version is in c:\windows\syswow64, the 64-bit version is in c:\windows\system32.

Comment: Do you have answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361085/created-preview-handler-for-outlook-giving-extra-message ?

Comment: Microsoft's big error on Win64 however, was using System32 for 64-bit files, SysWOW64 for 32-bit files, and redirecting the former to the latter in 32-bit mode. They should have done the reverse, with System64 for 64-bit files and a redirect in 64-bit mode...

Comment: @Medinoc, my educated guess: they probably tried that first, and it probably caused way more compatibility problems than with the approach that was actually taken. I'd love to hear some of the stories...